# Is it possible to friends list of a user using user id without access token in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

First of all i am sorry for this simple question, but i am not sure about this.

In my application i am using fb and linked in for logging in. if user logging in from facebook means i can get the friend list of specific user using access token. If user logging in through linked in means i am unable to get the friend list of specific users.

I know that i can get friends list by passing `user_id/friends` in graph API with my facebook login. I want to know that without getting access token from facebook can we get the friends list of given user_id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can not get a Facebook user’s friend list without a valid user access token for that user.

Comment: @CBroe - you should add that as an Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not get a Facebook user’s friend list without a valid user access token for that user.